# can I write a function that writes the printf type output of another function into a .txt file in C?

Tags: c, printf, fopen

I would like to know how to create a function that gathers the outputs of other functions and writes them into a txt file using C.
To be clear, the function outputs that I want to write are all of them of the type printf.
I'm guessing that I have to use the frpintf function, but I don't really know how in this case.
This is one of the functions with a printf output that I'm interested in.

```
void max_pixel(const char *filename){
    int red=0, green=0, blue=0, i, j, width, height, n, max=0, absc=0, ordo=0, sum=0;
    unsigned char *data;
    read_image_data(filename, &data, &width, &height, &n);
    for (i=0; i<height ; i++){
        for (j=0; j<width ; j++){
            
            pixelRGB* pixel;
            pixel = get_pixel(data,width,height,n,j,i);
            sum=pixel->R + pixel->G + pixel->B;
            if(max<sum){
                red=pixel->R;
                green=pixel->G;
                blue=pixel->B;
                absc=j;
                ordo=i;
                max=sum;

            }
        }
    }
    printf("max pixel (%d, %d): %d, %d, %d\n", absc, ordo, red, green, blue);
}
```

And this is the function I'm trying to use to write the previous function's output into a txt file.

```
void stat_report(const char *filename){
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("stat_report.txt", "w");
    max_pixel(filename);
    fprintf(fp, , ,);  // Help needed here

    fclose(fp);
}
```

As you can see, I don't know what to put inside the fprintf function.

I hope someone can give me a helping hand and thank you for your time.

Comment: You have approximately two options (I may have missed something).   (1) Revise the code to call `fprintf(logfp, "max pixel …", …)` instead of `printf()`, and have `logfp` default to `stdout` to retain current behaviour.  You can then open the log file and reassign `logfp` to point to that.  (2) (Temporarily?) redirect standard output to your log file.  That's fiddlier — you still open the log file, but you have to use `freopen()` to change the meaning of `stdout`, and if you want to return to the original standard output, then you have to arrange to preserve that too.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Option (1) is better if you can modify the relevant code.  Option (2) becomes necessary if you can't modify the relevant code.  The `logfp` variable is probably a global variable, rather like `stdout` is a global variable and for similar reasons.  Note that on modern Linux, you cannot simply write `FILE *logfp = stdout;` at file scope — the initializer won't work.  So, you have to write `FILE *logfp = NULL;` and then ensure that `logfp` is set to `stdout` if it is `NULL`.  Consider whether the log file should be opened with `"a"` mode instead of `"w"`.

Comment: You might be able to use file descriptors behind the scenes to support the redirection of standard output — but be cautious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` writes to `stdout`, or the "Standard Output", which is *normally* the console.

What you want to do is *redirect* `stdout` to a file instead of the normal console.

The way to do that is with function `freopen`.
The call is:

```
freopen("output.txt", "a+", stdout);
```

That is, you want to "reopen" `stdout` to instead direct to `output.txt`.

After that, any output to `stdout` (such as `printf`) will instead go to `"output.txt"`

---

One thing to be cautious of:  If you're working in a large complex system with other developers, just because you redirected `stdout` doesn't mean it will stick.  Another developer, another thread, another component, etc, might redirect stdout for its own purposes, and you would lose your redirection.   In otherwords, this is not a great technique for a large-scale system with many components and developers.

Comment: Thanks, it worked very smoothly. Actually, I am working in a system with other developers so I hope nobody needs to redirect stdout, but in case it happens, is there a way to keep using freopen? Perhaps by using fprintf instead of print in the first place, as Yano said, in order to redirect the output of the function anywhere but to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and `fprintf` are exactly the same, except `printf` writes to `stdout` and `fprintf` lets you specify the output file stream.  From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html):

> The `fprintf()` function shall place output on the named output
> stream.  The `printf()` function shall place output on the standard
> output stream stdout.

For example

```
printf("max pixel (%d, %d): %d, %d, %d\n", absc, ordo, red, green, blue);
```

is exactly the same as

```
fprintf(stdout, "max pixel (%d, %d): %d, %d, %d\n", absc, ordo, red, green, blue);
```

Therefore, if you're opening a file `fp`, simply pass that to `fprintf` and use the same `printf` format string and arguments:

```
fprintf(fp, "max pixel (%d, %d): %d, %d, %d\n", absc, ordo, red, green, blue);
```